# Hapi server not able to load public files under different views folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, hapi.js

I have a directory app/server/views/ wherein all the jade files are present. As my application is now beginning to have more jade files, I thought of structuring app/server/views/ based on category of actors for simplicity & maintainence. Something like:

- app/server/views/admin/task1.jade
- app/server/views/admin/task2.jade
- app/server/views/superadmin/task1.jade
- app/server/views/superadmin/task2.jade
- app/server/views/user/task1.jade
- app/server/views/user/task2.jade

If all the jade files are present inside /app/server/views/ directory, my index.js file has no problem in loading the jade files. However on structuring per above mentioned directory format, I run into issues:

```
server.views({
    engines: 
    {
       jade: require('jade') 
    },
    path: [ __dirname + "/app/server/views/admin", __dirname + "/app/server/views/superadmin", __dirname + "/app/server/views/user" ]
});
```

With the above index file, my jade files won't load.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think path can be an array.  From the docs, I gather that it should be one directory.

Something like `path: Path.join( __dirname, 'app/server/views' )` then call the templates from your controller as `reply( 'admin/task1', ....)`.

If you can determine your actor's role programatically and have exactly the same code, then something like `reply( actorsRole + '/task1' )` should do the trick.

Comment: I guess reply takes care of coding the server and provides options therein. But isn't there a way to restructure the views directory. It looks messy if path can be an array of paths.

Comment: If you look at the doc (please let me know which version you are using and I will give you a pointer), there are ways to specify the layouts, partials and helpers paths but I have never used them myself.

Comment: I am using hapi version "~8.4.0"

Comment: You will find the documentation [here](http://hapijs.com/api/8.4.0#serverviewsoptions). Note that in versions 9.x, views have their own plugin called `vision` (but the doc is still applicable). Can you clarify why you think it's messy as described in my answer ?

Comment: I meant that thing would look messy if path can't be an array, as views folder would not organised. For now I can live with alternate approach that you suggested. Thanks!